# Getting Facebook Album Photo's on External Website using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization

I'm trying to get Facebook album data on a site, using the Facebook Graph API.
  I'm trying to do so via Ajax or Postman but I can't get it to work.

I can make a normal `https://graph.facebook.com/me` call and get my name (i.e. this shows that I got the proper access token in Postman and can see the JSON).

It's when I try to do a call to get the JSON for the album that I get this error below (again the access token is there like the call above)

From the URL, I get the `ID` of the album:
`https://www.facebook.com/amir.sobhi.94/media_set?set=a.693877XXx02412.100004404098018&type=3`

**and the error was ...**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '693877XXx02412' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DHWlSshJtTU"
  }
}
```

Comment: What request did you do when you got that error?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing the necessary permission to see the album.

Comment: @CBroe - I think you're right, the only thing is that I can't figure out where to give a given access token permission

Comment: @WizKid - good point I missed that - the Request was `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/693877XXx02412?debug=true` as this page claims: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/album